# Lookup failed error while trying to lookup a local EJB Session from a standalone POJO class inside a servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, lookup, session-bean

In a Java EE application I have coded a layout manager class. From this class, sometimes i need to access EJB Session from the EJB module.

Here is the code and this is generated code:

```
private MessagesFacadeLocal lookupMessagesFacadeLocal() {
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        return (MessagesFacadeLocal) c.lookup("java:global/CMS/CMS-ejb/MessagesFacade!cms.model.beans.MessagesFacadeLocal");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
        throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
}
```

But, while trying to use this, I get an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException:
>
> **Lookup failed for 'java:global/CMS/CMS-ejb/MessagesFacade!cms.model.beans.MessagesFacadeLocal'**
>
> in SerialContext[myEnv= {java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CMS]

I am not sure why I am getting this problem. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the "CMS" context can't be found, so I would guess your application name is not actually "CMS".  What does lookup("java:app/AppName") return?

If your EJB module is in the same application, you could use lookup("java:app/CMS-ejb-/..."), which gives you a bit more flexibility in changing your application name anyway.

Comment: CMS is actually the application name.. CMS-war and CMS-ejb are the two different modules in the app.

Comment: Is "CMS" the application name as reported by lookup("java:app/AppName")?

Comment: No, When i run from the web module, it returns `CMS-war` as the appName.

Comment: And when I use ("java:app/CMS-ejb")... I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy157 cannot be cast to cms.model.beans.MessagesFacadeLocal` error

Comment: And the class from which I am trying to lookup is a POJO class. (I just found out this term is used)

Comment: Are you sure that CMS-war and CMS-ejb are being deployed as part of the same EAR rather than as independent modules? The AppName result of CMS-war and the ClassCastException (implying distinct class loaders) makes me wonder. Well, traditional ClassCastException debug would be to print lookup("java:app/CMS-ejb").getClass().getClassLoader() and MessageFacadeLocal.class.getClassLoader() to see if they differ.

Comment: Actually I am unsure, I am using Netbeasn as my IDe, and by default I created the Enterprise Web Application which does deploy both CMS-war adn CMS-ejb as part of same EAR, at least I think it does.

Comment: "Enterprise Web Application" sounds like an option to create a WAR.

Comment: It creates two packages with one application.. ejb and war.. I am sure of this.. because I didn't create war and ejb modules differently.